# using a subquery with UPDATE

Tags: sql, pervasive

can any one help me make this sql statement work?
my dbms doesnt all INNER JOINS with UPDATES so I have to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET i2.BVRTLPRICE01 = i1.BVRTLPRICE01
WHERE exists
(SELECT *
FROM INVENTORY i1
INNER JOIN INVENTORY i2 ON i2.CODE = REPLACE(i1.CODE, 'U', 'S')
WHERE i1.CODE = 'UEOABAA000_005'
)
```

Right now its giving me a syntax error that i2 and i1 do not exist in the query, not sure what im supposed to do to make this work?

thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot update the table you're currently selecting from.

Comment: Also, you can rewrite this query using `join`, but you need to specify the dbms name.

Comment: @zerkms the DBMS is called pervasive , but like i mentioned i cant do inner joins on updates with this DBMS

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL (MS SQLServer) it will be like this:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET i2.BVRTLPRICE01 = i1.BVRTLPRICE01
FROM  INVENTORY i1
INNER JOIN INVENTORY i2 ON i2.CODE = REPLACE(i1.CODE, 'U', 'S')
WHERE i1.CODE = 'UEOABAA000_005'
```

You might interchange i2/i1.